# QGIS - raster georeference copy

Tags: qgis, raster

Basically is it possible to copy georeferenced information from one raster (original) to another one (Photoshoped), not the tfw but actually header?

I looked hard but can't find any precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working on a GeoTiff file, you can use `OSGeo4w Shell` which comes with QGIS installation.

Let's say file names are:

- Original raster: `original.tif`
- Photoshopped raster: `retouched.tif`

Start `OSGeo4w Shell` and move to the directory (folder) you store the raster file `original.tif`. Then,

```
listgeo original.tif > original.gtf
geotifcp -g original.gtf retouched.tif output.tif
```

Above, first line will copy geotag from `original.tif` and save it as a `gtf` file. Second line will paste `gtf` to `retouched.tif` and return an output raster (`output.tif`).

It is common we corrupt geotags while Photoshop retouching the image, and `OSGeo4W` returns an error. Cleaning the retouched file beforehand may help.

```
listgeo original.tif > original.gtf
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co PROFILE=BASELINE retouched.tif retouched_clean.tif
geotifcp -g original.gtf retouched_clean.tif output.tif
```

You will find more detailed discussions in this site, but a basic outline (rundown) may be hard to find.